# Non-empty interior

Tags: elementary-set-theory, self-learning

I would like to verify a certain condition for a theorem. It requires that $\{(\theta,\rho\theta):\rho>0,\theta>0\}$ has a non-empty interior. I have trouble visualizing such sets can you guys help me see if this has a non-empty interior (and if it does, why?)

Comment: I assume $\theta,\rho$ are polar coordinates... Are the allowed values of $\theta$ restricted to some intervals of length $2\pi$ or not? Also, you write "such sets" in plural, but I see only one.

Comment: No, it was a pretty simple question. When it gets late I need to verify silly things like this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set is the first quadrant with both axis removed which it is open, so in particular has a nonempty interior.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Plotting it out helped me see it was indeed equivalent to the first quadrant (without the axis).